# Have PDF-Creator suppress warning dialog not to halt build process

Tags: msbuild, pdf-generation, wsh, auto-build

I have a **msbuild** script that includes creation of a few PDF's using **PDF creator**. It's the **Convert2PDF.vbs** that's being used, converting **doc's** to **PDF's**, and a while ago it stopped working and none seemed to take the time to fix it. So I looked into it and by debugging the script I found that it was in fact a document for which **Word** presented a dialog with information about contents being larger than the margins. This halted the entire thing since none could press this dialog during the auto-build.

So what I wonder is if there is a way to tell the **PDF Creator** script, via cmd line arguments or by altering the script, to suppress these kinds of warnings and just continue with conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a script in word that suppressed warnings if the given document resided within the build folder specified.